# Structure of Derived Category of Sheaves on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. We will be working in the topological category. Let $A \in D^b(C):=$ bounded derived category of sheaves on $C$. Is it true that $$A \cong \oplus H^i(A)$$

If not(My guess is it is not), what would be a counterexample?

How about the same question in algebraic setting, where the category in question is bounded derived category of Coherent sheaves?

Is it rare for a bounded(below) derived category of an Abelian category to have such a property? Is it possible to know when above equality will be true?

Comment: If $Ext^i(A,B) = 0$ for all $i>1$ and for all $A,B$ in an abelian category, then any object in the bounded derived category is isomorphic to the (shifted) sum of its cohomology objects. This holds for the category of coherent sheaves on a smooth projective curve, but does not hold in the topological setting.

Comment: @ulrich Thanks! This is quite helpful. May is ask if it is possible to know if such an equality will true for a given object $A$ in the derived category?

Comment: For a given object $A$ in the derived category, I suppose it might suffice for the vanishing of the Exts to hold for all pairs of cohomology objects of $A$ but I have not checked this.